# Return meta value associated w/ meta key wp_usermeta table belonging to a user ID from wp_users table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to export user information from the wp_users and wp_usermeta tables with the following query:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.display_name, a.user_login, a.user_email FROM wp_users a, wp_usermeta b  WHERE a.ID=(SELECT b.user_id WHERE b.meta_key = 'wp_s2member_custom_fields' AND b.meta_value LIKE '%companyName%')
```

This works but **how do I also return the meta_value associated with the meta_key** 'wp_s2member_custom_fields'?

Essentially I want to return a row for each user who belongs to company 'companyName', this row has information from wp_users (id, email, fname, lname) along with info from the wp_usermeta table (wp_s2member_custom_fields).

Desired output:

```
wp_users.ID | wp_users.display_name | wp_users.login | wp_users.email | wp_usermeta.wp_s2member_custom_fields.meta_value
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [join](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-using-joins.htm) (untested):

```
SELECT a.ID, a.display_name, a.user_login, a.user_email, b.meta_value FROM wp_users a JOIN wp_usermeta b ON a.ID = b.user_id WHERE b.meta_key = 'wp_s2member_custom_fields' AND b.meta_value LIKE '%companyName%')
```

But since you are using WordPress you could look into [WP_User_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query) and [get_user_meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta)

I do hope you are using `global $wpdb;` instead of creating an own database connection. https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb